# Showing Parameter Prompt when loading Crystal Report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Crystal Report Showing Parameter Prompt when the  report loading.

My Code to load a report is:-

```
TableLogOnInfo logOnInfo = new TableLogOnInfo();

                logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerName"];
                logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DBName"];
                logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = false;
                logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UID"];
                logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PWD"];

                foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table tbl in SchoolExpenseReport.ReportDocument.Database.Tables)
                    tbl.ApplyLogOnInfo(logOnInfo);

                ParameterValues pvSchoolExpense = new ParameterValues();
                ParameterDiscreteValue pdvFomDate = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
                ParameterDiscreteValue pdvToDate = new ParameterDiscreteValue();

                pdvFomDate.Value = txtFromDate.Text;
                pdvToDate.Value = txtToDate.Text;

                SchoolExpenseReport.ReportDocument.DataDefinition.ParameterFields["FromDate"].CurrentValues.Clear();
                pvSchoolExpense.Add(pdvFomDate);
                SchoolExpenseReport.ReportDocument.DataDefinition.ParameterFields["FromDate"].ApplyCurrentValues(pvSchoolExpense);

                SchoolExpenseReport.ReportDocument.DataDefinition.ParameterFields["ToDate"].CurrentValues.Clear();
                pvSchoolExpense.Add(pdvToDate);
                SchoolExpenseReport.ReportDocument.DataDefinition.ParameterFields["ToDate"].ApplyCurrentValues(pvSchoolExpense);

                SchoolExpenseReportViewer.ReportSource = SchoolExpenseReport;
                SchoolExpenseReportViewer.DataBind();
                SchoolExpenseReportViewer.RefreshReport();
                SchoolExpenseReport.Visible = true;
```

Showing the Parameter prompt as below
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with adding parameters like that. I usually use `.SetParameterValue()`.

When I've set dates as the parameter value, they're usually in the `DateTime` format, but I see you're just assigning string values.

Try changing this:

```
pdvFomDate.Value = txtFromDate.Text;
pdvToDate.Value = txtToDate.Text;
```

To this (change the format string based on whatever the date looks like in the `TextBox`):

```
pdvFomDate.Value = DateTime.ParseExact(txtFromDate.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy");
pdvToDate.Value = DateTime.ParseExact(txtToDate.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy");
```

FWIW, I'd consider using a date picker control instead of a text box to accept date values from the user.

---

If that doesn't work, try this alternative syntax for setting parameter values:

```
var fromDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtFromDate.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy");

SchoolExpenseReport.ReportDocument.SetParameterValue("FromDate", fromDate);
```

Comment: I having another page which only having Drop Down List but the same occurring on the page.